# How do I run docker checkpoint on mac hosts

Tags: docker

I'm on a Mac host running Docker Desktop and I'd like to use [docker checkpoint](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/checkpoint/) to save the state of my docker images between reboots. Taking information from the following unix.stackexchange post, I've enabled experimental options via Docker Desktop preferences:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/533009/how-to-pause-a-docker-container-then-reboot-host-system-and-unpause-container

Since I've enabled experimental options, I now have access to `docker checkpoint` on the command line. However, when I try to create a checkpoint I get a complaint about `criu` not being found:

```
$ docker checkpoint create post_deletes_cache before_reboot
Error response from daemon: Cannot checkpoint container post_deletes_cache: runc did not terminate successfully: CRIU version check failed: exec: "criu": executable file not found in $PATH path= /var/run/desktop-containerd/daemon/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/moby/2debfb8bab77b8e5baf7020118f1101cb8b9109a66f27f6dcc756faa630ff836/criu-dump.log: unknown
```

Clearly I'll need `criu` installed in the docker for mac VM in order for `docker checkpoint` to work. I'm confused by what I find online about this. Maybe there was a temporary solution for Docker on MacOS that used to work but now no longer works? Can someone help me run `docker checkpoint` on my Mac host?